# In Hybris backoffice how do I add another tab in explorer tree for managing (create, search, delete) instances of some items?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris Back Office, how do I add another tab in the explorer tree for managing (create, search, delete) instances of some items?

I can't really find anything on the subject.

Do I need to use the already available UI for it or add my own widget?

Answer (score 0):

In your ***-backoffice-config.xml** file, you have to add something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>


<config xmlns="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config"
        xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config/hybris"
        xmlns:wz="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/wizard-config"
        xmlns:list-view="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/listView"
        xmlns:editorArea="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/editorArea"
        xmlns:explorer-tree="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/explorertree"
        xmlns:simple-search="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/simplesearch"
        xmlns:advanced-search="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/advancedsearch"
        xmlns:df="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/dynamicForms"
        xmlns:dsb="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/dashboard"
>

    <context merge-by="module" parent="auto" component="explorer-tree">
        <explorer-tree:explorer-tree xmlns:explorer-tree="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/explorertree">
            <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="backoffice.myCustomItemType">
                <explorer-tree:type-node code="MyCustomItemType" id="MyCustomItemType"/>
            </explorer-tree:navigation-node>
        </explorer-tree:explorer-tree>
    </context>

    <context type="MyCustomItemType" component="listview">
        <list:list-view xmlns:list="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/listView">
            <list:column qualifier="customAttribute1" />
            <list:column qualifier="customAttribute2" />
        </list:list-view>
    </context>

</config>
```

Like way, you can configure "editorArea", "advanced-search", "create-wizard" etc by refering any OOTB backoffice-config.xml file.

Find [this document](http://www.novusedu.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/19-Hybris-BackOffice-Cust.pdf) for the steps.